# Spring Security with Java Configuration: How to handle BadCredentialsException from a custom provider

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

I need to authenticate some rest services using a token id in the url (or maybe in the request header - but this is not important for now). I am trying to use java configuration to set this up using as a guide this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826293/restful-authentication-via-spring). My problem is that I do not know how to handle "BadCredentialsException" that is thrown when the authentication fails from the provider. Here is my Security Config:

```java
public static class SecurityConfigForRS extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
            throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.regexMatcher("^/rest.*")
                .addFilterBefore(
                        new TokenAuthenticationFilter(
                                authenticationManagerBean()),
                        AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .and().csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

For now I skip the other implementations - if it helps I will post them later.

When the token is missing or is invalid, the `TokenAuthernticationProvider` throws a `BadCredentialsException`. I need to catch this and send back an `401-Unauthorized`. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first Filter I created was a subclass of **GenericFilterBean** and it did not have support for authentication failure handler or success handler. However **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** supports success and failure handlers. My filter is as simple as that:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends
    AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

public TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
        RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
    super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException,
        IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication auth = new TokenAuthentication("-1");
    try {
        Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
        if (!params.isEmpty() && params.containsKey("auth_token")) {
            String token = params.get("auth_token")[0];
            if (token != null) {
                auth = new TokenAuthentication(token);
            }
        }
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(auth);
    } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
        unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, ae);
    }
    return auth;
}}
```

and my http security is:

```
    public static class SecurityConfigForRS extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
            throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter getTokenAuthFilter()
            throws Exception {
        TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter tapf = new TokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                new RegexRequestMatcher("^/rest.*", null));
        tapf.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return tapf;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.regexMatcher("^/rest.*")
                .addFilterAfter(getTokenAuthFilter(),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

The filter chain order ***does*** matter! I placed it after BasicAuthenticationFilter and it works fine. Of course there might be a better solution but for now this works!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with Global Exception handling with **ControllerAdvice**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;    
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice    
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler // when Invalid Credentials
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleInvalidCredentialsException(
            BadCredentialsException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(
                new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    class ErrorMessage {
        private String error;
    }
}
```