# Security configuration without XML with custom filters?

Tags: spring, api, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using **Spring Boot** in STS to build a simple REST API.

I have some basic security requirements, similar to the ones described in the original post here: [RESTful Authentication via Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826293/restful-authentication-via-spring)

The accepted answer above seems like a valid solution but does not translate to Spring Boot due to the lack of XML configuration.

How would I configure my Spring Boot application in the same manner?

Comment: You can still use xml with sprnig boot. Simply use a `@ImportResource` to include the xml configuration. Spring Boot already configures Spring Security for you. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-security.html. How to configure Spring Security with Java based configuration is explained in the Spring Security Reference guide, see  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc.

Comment: Thank you M. Deinum, these look like solid references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same code as in that post if you want (are you sure that's what you want?) with `@Configuration`. The `HttpSecurity` builder has methods `addFilter()`, `addFilterBefore()`, `addFilterAfter()`, so you use those instead of the `<custom-filter/>` element in XML. Most (if not all) XML elements translate pretty directly into Java config.