# JAX-RS REST API Basic Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, rest, basic-authentication

i am trying to implement basic authentication to somehow secure my rest api.To test, i tried below code to filter the url parameter that contains users however it is not aborting the request without authorization.  and  the most important is i need to implement it in the way that only update and delete needs to be authorized with the respective username and password. other things i just don't want to filter. i have an user class having username and password (encrypted) properties. so if the url contains PUT or delete method on users/{userID} i want it to verify with the username and password of that specific users. i have listed code of model , resources and filter class below.. i really need your help. thanks in advance.

filter class.

```
package Authentication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Base64;


@Provider
public class SecureFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String Auth_Header = "Authorization";
    private static final String Auth_Header_Prefix = "Basic ";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath().contains("users")) {
            List<String> authHeader = requestContext.getHeaders().get(Auth_Header);
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.size() > 0) {
                String authToken = authHeader.get(0);
                authToken = authToken.replaceFirst(Auth_Header_Prefix, "");
                String decodedString = Base64.decodeAsString(authToken);
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(decodedString, ":");
                String userName = tokenizer.nextToken();
                String password = tokenizer.nextToken();
                if ("user".equals(userName) && "password".equals(password)) {
                    return;
                }
                Response unauthorizedstatus = Response
                        .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .entity("these resources needs authorization. ")
                        .build();
                requestContext.abortWith(unauthorizedstatus);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

resource class:

```
import com.mycompany.samplehospital.model.Alert;
import com.mycompany.samplehospital.model.Message;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


import com.mycompany.samplehospital.model.User;

import com.mycompany.samplehospital.Services.UserServices;
import com.mycompany.samplehospital.exception.objectNotFound;
import com.mycompany.samplehospital.Services.AlertServices;
import com.mycompany.samplehospital.Services.MessageServices;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 *
 * @author sandesh poudel
 */
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/users")
public class userResources {


 UserServices service ;
 public userResources() throws Exception{
     service = new UserServices();
 }





    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getAllUser(){
    return UserServices.getUsers();


    }
    @Path("/{userId}")

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public User getUser(@PathParam("userId") int ID ) throws Exception{
        User myUserList = service.getUser(ID);
        if (myUserList == null){
        throw new objectNotFound("User not Found"); 
        }else {
            return myUserList;
        }

    }


    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)


    public User addUser(User user ) throws Exception{

        return service.AddUser(user);



    }
}


    @PUT
        @Path("/{userId}")

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)


    public User updtaeUser(User user) throws Exception{

    return service.updateUser(user);

    }
    @DELETE 
      @Path("/{userId}")
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

    public User delUser(@PathParam("userId") int ID) throws Exception{

        return service.removeUser(ID);


    }
    @Path("/{userId}/messages")

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

    public  List<Message> getAllMessageByUser(@PathParam("userId") int ID) throws Exception{
        MessageServices mservice = new MessageServices();

        List<Message> messageUserList = mservice.getAllMessageByUser(ID);
        if (messageUserList == null ){
            throw new objectNotFound("messages not Found"); 

        } return messageUserList;

        }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/{userId}/alerts")


    public List<Alert> AlertsResources(@PathParam("userId") int userId){
        AlertServices myAlert = new AlertServices();


        List<Alert> newAlertUserList = myAlert.getAllAlertByUser(userId) ;
        if (newAlertUserList == null){
            throw new objectNotFound("messages not Found"); 

        } return newAlertUserList;


    }
```

Model class User

```
package com.mycompany.samplehospital.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import Authentication.HashPassword;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author sandeshpoudel
 */
@XmlRootElement

public  class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String title;
    private int age;
    private String Sex;
    private String Address;
    private int phoneNo;
    private String fullName;
    private int id;
    private Map<Integer, Message> allMessage;
    private Map<Integer,Alert> allAlerts;
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private HashPassword hs ;





    public User() {
    }


    public User(int id,String fullName, String Sex, Integer age, Integer  phoneNumber, String Address, String title,String userName,String password) throws Exception {
        hs = new HashPassword();
        this.id= id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.title = title;
        this.age = age;
        this.Sex = Sex;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNumber;
         setPassWord(password);
       // setPassWord(passWord) uncomment this and remove next line to execute on encryption mode;


        this.userName= userName;

    }
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id= id;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setSex(String Sex) {
        this.Sex = Sex;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(int phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public  void setPassWord(String passWord) throws Exception {

                hs = new HashPassword();
                this.passWord = hs.encrypt(passWord);


      //  this.passWord = passWord;
    }




@XmlElement
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    /*

    */
@XmlElement
  public int getId(){
    return id;
}
@XmlElement

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
@XmlElement

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
@XmlElement

    public String getSex() {
        return Sex;
    }
@XmlElement

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
@XmlElement

    public int getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }
   @XmlTransient
    public Map<Integer, Message> getAllMessage() {
    return allMessage;
}
    public void setAllMessage(Map<Integer, Message> allMessage) {
    this.allMessage = allMessage;
}   @XmlTransient

    public Map<Integer, Alert> getAllAlerts() {
    return allAlerts;
}
    public void setAllAlerts(Map<Integer, Alert> allAlerts) {
    this.allAlerts = allAlerts;
    }


  @Override
    public String toString(){
        return (getSex() +" "+ getAddress()+" "+ getPhoneNo() +" "+ getFullName());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set up spring security, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826293/restful-authentication-via-spring).

Answer (score 2):

Basic authentication is part of the servlet specification. So if you run in a servlet container, which is the case, you can just enable basic authentication in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>all-content</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>foo-realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

You must also configure the realm, and the roles, this depend on your servlet container implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running you app in a Java EE Container you can use standard web security defined in web.xml
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm#GKBAA

Or if you use Spring
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Answer (score 0):

In a sample jax rs api, I implemented basic authentication by getting the HttpServletRequest in my rest resource.

I created a doAuthorize() method which extract the Authentication header, decode and validate authentication as you have done.

Then I call doAuthorize() in the resource path methods which need it.